# Using loop to go through range to select a single value each time

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a for loop or list comprehension that can go through a range, extract a single value each time by moving through each index in order, store it and then compare it to another value.
for example:

```
def home():
    for i in range (1,10):
        ###not sure how to extract one by one
        ### take that single value that was extracted from the range above and 
        reduce  it from a index of type int
        t_1 = (board[0] - i )
        ### call upon a function and plug in result:
        reducer(t_1)
        if reducer is True:
             print ('hello world')
        else:
            home()
```

So basically the function home() runs in loops until it finds the correct number in the range, plugs it in as a parameter to the function reducer(t_1) and returns the result. 
The issue is I cannot understand how to create that first for loop or list comprehension to extract that single value one at a time from the required range, store it and then valuate it.

Comment: How about `t_all = [board[0]-i for i in range(1,10)]`. Now, `t_all` will contain all the `t_1`s and then you can send this list to `reducer`

Comment: `if reducer is True` - `reducer` is a function, so it's truth value is always `True`.  Do you mean `if reducer(t_1):...` so that the value returned by `reducer` is evaluated?  (Side note: in an `if` statement, the expression following the `if` is always evaluated as a boolean - True or False - so appending `is True` or `is False` is redundant.  `if x:` or `if not x:` are enough).

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question, this is what you mean I assume:

```
t_all = [board[0]-i for i in range(1,10)]
```

Using list comprehension, you loop over 1 to 10 and then subtract each of the values from `board[0]` and store all of them in a list. You can then pass the list to your function.

Comment: I want to subtract all values in t_all from board [0] but one at a time. not all at once. for example:

Comment: But that's what you were already doing in your code. What's the problem then? Do you want to put the function call of `home()` in a for loop?